# How to list files on USB OTG device

Tags: android, usb, usb-otg

I know how to do following:

- listen to attach and detach events of usb devices
- getting all attached devices
- getting permissions for a device

So in the end I have an `UsbDevice` and I have permissions to read/write it. How to go on from here?

I can open the device and get a `FileDescriptor` like following:

```
 UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
 UsbInterface intf = device.getInterface(0);
 UsbEndpoint endpoint = intf.getEndpoint(0);
 UsbDeviceConnection connection = manager.openDevice(device);
 boolean interfaceClaimed = connection.claimInterface(intf, true);
 int fileDescriptor = connection.getFileDescriptor();
```

*How can I work with this `FileDescriptor` now? Or how else can I access the files on the USB device?*

**EDIT**

- *Solution for android < 6*: Don't open a `UsbDeviceConnection` and just try to find the usb devices path. Still, then you have the problem to distinguish between multiple usb devices and don't know which path belongs to which device...
- *Solution for android >= 6*: Use the Storage Access Framework, actually I don't know how this works yet...

Comment: Mostly the stick will be mounted on a file system folder like /storage/usbdrive or so. Under Marshmellow that path is not there and you can use the Storage Access Framework.

Comment: I edited my question and added some things. Actually do you know how to distinguish between the usb devices? I can find all available paths to the usb storages, but I don't know which path belongs to which device

Comment: Never saw more then one usbdrive path. Where do you see more?

Comment: via usb otg you can mount anything, usb drive pen, external hard disc or even an external card reader with eventually many cards in it...

Comment: Yes. And what paths do you see when there are many cards in it? Which device is showing that?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself yet (I don't have a card reader) but I've read already from mounts like "UsbDriveA", "UsbDriveB" or similar names that let me assume, that it would work...

Comment: Just tried to list the files on the usb device => it does not work. `file.listFiles()` return null... According to the documentation, this happens if an IO exception occurs... So it seems like that way is not working at all...

Comment: What is file.getAbsolutePath() when you do the listFiles()? listFiles would return null if there are no files. Or if you did not request the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

Comment: Path is `/mnt/media_rw/UsbDriveA` and there are files on the usb drive...

Comment: Another question: with the `storage access provider` you mean following solution: start an intent with `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` and let the user select the usb device and then use `DocumentFile`s to access data on the usb storage... This means, I have to check if the user really selected the usb storage (or at least a folder on the usb device) and not the internal storage and then I get access to the folder the user selected + all data underneath it... I got this working, but telling the user to select the root directory of the usb device is a challenging thing for many...

Comment: Indeed. The usb drive is clearly marked as such. So trust the users of your app.

Comment: Actually I do trust in that. But not, that they select the root folder... But thanks for the hints and tipps...

Comment: @prom85 Are you still seeking help for this question? I noticed I was the only poster, I added a lot of info on my "alternate" method, which may be useful for 6.0 Marshmallow compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

Because I am as stumped as you are, I would go the route of using the `ls` command.

Code example:

```
try {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls /storage/UsbDriveA");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    String listOfFiles = "";
    String line;
    while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
      listOfFiles += line;
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

`ls` will return `no such file or directory` if the mount point is incorrect.

Here is a list of many of the mount points manufacturers use:

```
/storage/UsbDriveA     (all Samsung devices)
/storage/USBstorage1   (LG G4, V10, G3, G2, other LG devices)
/storage/usbdisk       (Moto Maxx, Turbo 2, Moto X Pure, other Motorola devices)
/storage/usbotg        (Sony Xperia devices, Lenovo Tabs)
/storage/UDiskA        (Oppo devices)
/storage/usb-storage   (Acer Iconia Tabs)
/storage/usbcard       (Dell Venue -- Vanilla Android 4.3 tablet)
/storage/usb           (HTC One M7, and some Vanilla Android devices)
```

(Based on my collection of devices and 3 other people's, and a quick trip to Bestbuy for testing the latest flagships. The only popular devices I know I'm missing are Hawuei/Xioami devices based in China, which are becoming popular in English countries, but likely they use one of the above.)

To find the right mount point, you would listen for `no such file or directory` and loop/re-execute the `exec()` statement with the next mount point.

Once all that is done, you can easily read files by using `cat /storage/.../file.txt` and write by using redirection: `echo test > /storage/.../file.txt`

Hope this helps